# Could an ultralight hypothetically takeoff without power on if it were windy enough?

Tags: takeoff, ultralight

I don't know if takeoff would be the right term, but the wing should generate lift with any headwind.

Comment: That works only if the aircraft is somehow prevented from getting blown away. The concept of kite-flying applies.

Answer (score 4):

It could, but eventually drag would cause the ultralight to start moving in the same direction as the wind and it would lose any apparent forward airspeed.

Comment: And if you tow it to the ground so it doesn’t move too much with the wind you have a kite.

Answer (score 1):

A wing will produce lift when exposed to a headwind. And yes, if the wind is strong enough, a properly tethered airplane, ultralight or not, will 'become unstuck'.

Comment: Even a tethered A380 could become "unstuck" with the right wind. The OP didn't mention tethering though.

Answer (score 0):

The ultralight could takeoff with a strong enough headwind, but would be blown away in the process. This would not only be..ahem...very dangerous, but would cause the ultralight to lose a lot of airspeed. If it were tethered to the ground, it would fly like a kite. The wind would pick it up, and the strings or rope would prevent it from losing control or flying away.